# Populate Pivot Table from a Comma Delimited Field in a Data Flow Task in SSIS

Tags: t-sql, csv, ssis, pivot-table

This is my 1st post, so be gentle :). I am building an SSIS package to collect information on jobs running throughout the enterprise at work. The goal is to have tables filled with info on Servers, Instance, DBs, Jobs, and their relations to each other. Ideally I will use merge commands to update or insert where necessary but for now it just inserts. Here is an overview of my package (keep your mind out of the gutter please :P):

(restrictions on hyperlinks for new users means you need to replace the + signs with "t"s in my links

http://img262.imageshack.us/i/package.jpg/

The 1st Data Flow task pulls in a list of instances to check from a flat text file and stores them in a record set. The foreach loop then goes through each one of them and changes my source Connection Manager's Connection string appropriately. Inside the loop we are going through 1 instance at a time. The "Process Server" Dataflow task is used to find the Server name and add it to the Destination DB if it doesn't exist, either way it also stores the Server ID and Name in package variables. The "Process Instance" does the same as the above but for the Instance instead. The "Collect DB Data" Task then uses those package variables to insert all the DBs in that instance as records with the Package variables mentioned above for Foreign keys. Once that is Finished we move on to the "Collect Job Data" task (hopefully the final task for this package). The following is the contents of the last task:

http://img809.imageshack.us/i/dataflow.png/

So inside of this task this is what I'm doing so far. I use a query to collect Job Info with Maintenance plan data 1st. Here is the Query for the OLE DB Source:

```
--WRITTEN BY MAXWELL WALLACE
--THE PURPOSE OF THIS QUERY IS TO COLLECT INFORMATION ABOUT JOBS AND MAINTENANCE PLANS
--RUNNING ON A PARTICULAR INSTANCE. IT COLLECTS NAMES, STATUSES, RUN TIMES AND DATES
--AS WELL AS DATABASES AFFECTED AND MAINTENANCE PLAN NAMES IF APPLICABLE.
SELECT B.NAME AS JOB_NAME, B.CATEGORY_ID, 
--RUN_STATUS CODE GETS TRANSLATED INTO ENGLISH
CASE A.RUN_STATUS
WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
ELSE 'Unknown'
END AS RUN_STATUS,
--CONVERT INTEGER DATE INTO SOMETHING MORE LEGABLE
SUBSTRING(CAST(A.RUN_DATE AS CHAR(8)),5,2) + '/' + 
RIGHT(CAST(A.RUN_DATE AS CHAR(8)),2) + '/' + 
LEFT(CAST(A.RUN_DATE AS CHAR(8)),4) AS RUN_DATE,
--CONVERT RUN_TIME INTO SOMETHING MORE RECONGNIZABLE (HH:MM:SS)
LEFT(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(A.RUN_TIME AS VARCHAR(10)),6),2) + ':' + 
SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(A.RUN_TIME AS VARCHAR(10)),6),3,2) + ':' + 
RIGHT(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(A.RUN_TIME AS VARCHAR(10)),6),2) AS RUN_TIME,
--CONVERT RUN_DURATION INTO SOMETHING MORE RECONGNIZABLE (HH:MM:SS)
LEFT(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(A.RUN_DURATION AS VARCHAR(10)),6),2) + ':' + 
SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(A.RUN_DURATION AS VARCHAR(10)),6),3,2) + ':' + 
RIGHT(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(A.RUN_DURATION AS VARCHAR(10)),6),2) AS RUN_DURATION,
--THE FOLLOWING SUBQUERY IS USED TO EXTRAPOLATE DETAILS FOR THE JOB IN IT'S MAINTENANCE PLAN (IF IT HAS 1)
--THE TOP 1 MAKES SURE WE GET ONLY 1 RECORD SINCE THIS IS A 1 TO MANY RELATIONSHIP
--THE LINE3 COLUMN CONTAINS DETAILS ABOUT THE TASK THAT WAS RUN
(SELECT TOP 1 E.LINE3 
    --WE START WITH THE SYSMAINTPLAN_LOG BECAUSE WE CAN (IN A WAY) JOIN IT TO OUR OUTER JOIN THROUGH THE PLAN_ID IN THE WHERE CLAUSE
    FROM MSDB.DBO.SYSMAINTPLAN_LOG AS D 
    --NOW IT IS POSSIBLE TO, BY EXTENTION, JOIN SYSMAINTPLAN_LOGDETAIL TO THE OUTER JOIN AS WELL THROUGH ITS 1 TO 1 RELATIONSHIP WITH SYSMAINTPLAN_LOG
    INNER JOIN MSDB.DBO.SYSMAINTPLAN_LOGDETAIL AS E ON E.TASK_DETAIL_ID = D.TASK_DETAIL_ID
    --THE 1ST PART OF THE WHERE RETURNS ONLY RECORDS OF THE SAME PLAN_ID, ESSENTIALLY "JOINING" THIS RECORD TO THE OUTER JOIN THE IN MAIN QUERY
    --THE 2ND PART MAKES SURE THE FIELD WE ACTUALLY CARE ABOUT CONTAINS MEANINGFUL DATA
    WHERE D.PLAN_ID = C.PLAN_ID AND E.LINE3 != '') AS PLAN_DETAILS, 
--THE FOLLOWING SUBQUERY RETURNS THE NAME OF THE MAINTENANCE PLAN (IF IT HAS 1)
(SELECT F.NAME
    FROM MSDB.DBO.SYSMAINTPLAN_PLANS AS F --THIS IS A SYSTEM GENERATED VIEW
    --LIKE THE ABOVE SUBQUERY, THIS WHERE ESSENTIALLY "JOINS" THIS RECORD TO THE OUTER JOIN IN THE MAIN QUERY
    WHERE F.ID = C.PLAN_ID) AS PLAN_NAME 
FROM MSDB.DBO.SYSJOBHISTORY AS A
INNER JOIN MSDB.DBO.SYSJOBS AS B ON A.JOB_ID = B.JOB_ID
--THIS OUTTER JOIN ATTACHES PLAN_IDS OF MAINTENANCE PLANS TO JOBS THAT HAVE THEM
LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSMAINTPLAN_SUBPLANS AS C ON C.JOB_ID = B.JOB_ID
--ONLY RETURN ENABLED JOBS
WHERE B.[ENABLED] = 1 
--AND ONLY JOB OUTCOMES, NOT EACH STEP
AND A.STEP_ID = 0 
--AND ONLY COMPLETED JOBS
AND A.RUN_STATUS <> 4
--SORTED BY LATEST DATE 1ST
ORDER BY A.RUN_DATE DESC
```

Sorry, but for some reason this forum doesn't preserve my formatting. Anyway, after that I add the package variable Instance ID as a column to assist in inserting these records with this Foreign Key. I convert some strings to unicode which is neither here nor there and then I do a conditional split on Records With a maintenance plan and records without. For records without I can Simply insert them into the destination and they are done! For records with a Maintenance plan however, the chance of them having a connection to one or more DB is very high. So, 1st I insert the job record into the Job table (exactly as I do with records not within a maintenance plan) and then I do a lookup to find the record I just inserted's ID. Next I take the field from my query that has a comma separated list of DBs affected by the Maintenance plan this job is part of and separate it into a VB.Net ArrayList. I then assign that ArrayList to a Package Variable.

This is the part I'm at. Obviously my next step is to create some sort of loop using the Job ID I just looked up and running through each variable in the ArrayList to insert them 1 at a time into the DB/Job Pivot table. Problem is I am not aware of how I can do a loop within a Data Flow Task and I can't think of a good way to move the pivot table insert out of this task. I might be able to do this with a script component but I am unsure how to preform inserts from within the script task (should I even consider that?). I am proficient with VB.Net and C# as well as TSQL so I can investigate any method of implementing this. Thanks in advance for your help. Cheers!

PS. Here is the table structure I am inserting the data into:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_SERVERS(
ID INT UNIQUE IDENTITY(1,1),
TITLE NVARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
CLUSTER_NAME NVARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
RESOURCES_USED NVARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '',
RESOURCE_THRESHOLD NVARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '',
IS_CLUSTERED BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)

CREATE TABLE TBL_INSTANCES(
ID INT UNIQUE IDENTITY(1,1),
SERVER_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES TBL_SERVERS(ID),
TITLE NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (SERVER_ID,TITLE))

CREATE TABLE TBL_CATEGORY_TYPES(
ID INT UNIQUE IDENTITY(1,1),
TITLE NVARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORY_TYPES VALUES ('LOCAL')
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORY_TYPES VALUES ('MULTISERVER')
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORY_TYPES VALUES ('NONE')

CREATE TABLE TBL_CATEGORY_CLASSES(
ID INT UNIQUE IDENTITY(1,1),
TITLE NVARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORY_CLASSES VALUES ('JOB')
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORY_CLASSES VALUES ('ALERT')
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORY_CLASSES VALUES ('OPERATOR')

CREATE TABLE TBL_CATEGORIES(
ID INT UNIQUE IDENTITY(1,1),
TITLE NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CATEGORY_CLASS_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES TBL_CATEGORY_CLASSES(ID),
CATEGORY_TYPE_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES TBL_CATEGORY_TYPES(ID),
PRIMARY KEY (TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID))

CREATE TABLE TBL_SQL_JOBS(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
TITLE NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
INSTANCE_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES TBL_INSTANCES(ID),
CATEGORY_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES TBL_CATEGORIES(ID),
RUN_STATUS NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
RUN_DATE NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
RUN_TIME NVARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
RUN_DURATION NVARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
MAINTENANCE_PLAN_NAME NVARCHAR(200),
RUN_INTERVAL NVARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '',
IS_ENABLED BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TBL_CATEGORIES ON
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (0,'[Uncategorized (Local)]',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (2,'[Uncategorized (Multi-Server)]',1,2,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (98,'[Uncategorized]',2,3,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (99,'[Uncategorized]',3,3,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (8,'Data Collector',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (7,'Database Engine Tuning Advisor',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (3,'Database Maintenance',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (5,'Full-Text',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (1,'Jobs from MSX',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (6,'Log Shipping',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (18,'REPL-Alert Response',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (16,'REPL-Checkup',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (10,'REPL-Distribution',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (11,'REPL-Distribution Cleanup',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (12,'REPL-History Cleanup',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (20,'Replication',2,3,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (13,'REPL-LogReader',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (14,'REPL-Merge',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (19,'REPL-QueueReader',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (15,'REPL-Snapshot',1,1,1)
INSERT INTO TBL_CATEGORIES (ID,TITLE,CATEGORY_CLASS_ID,CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_GROUP_ID) VALUES (17,'REPL-Subscription Cleanup',1,1,1)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TBL_CATEGORIES OFF

CREATE TABLE TBL_APPLICATIONS(
ID INT UNIQUE IDENTITY(1,1),
TITLE NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
HUB_SITE NVARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (TITLE,HUB_SITE))

CREATE TABLE TBL_DATABASES(
ID INT UNIQUE IDENTITY(1,1),
INSTANCE_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES TBL_INSTANCES(ID),
TITLE NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
APPLICATION_ID INT REFERENCES TBL_APPLICATIONS(ID),
MANAGED BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
CONNECTIONSTRING NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
RESOURCES_USED NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
RESOURCE_THRESHOLD NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
LAST_SEEN DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
PRIMARY KEY (INSTANCE_ID,TITLE))

CREATE TABLE TBL_DATABASE_JOBS(
ID INT UNIQUE IDENTITY(1,1),
DATABASE_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES TBL_DATABASES(ID),
JOB_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES TBL_SQL_JOBS(ID),
PRIMARY KEY (DATABASE_ID,JOB_ID))
```

And here is some sample results from the query I posted earlier. Keep in mind the script can be run against any instance as long as you used MSDB because it uses all system generated tables and views:

http://img253.imageshack.us/i/resultsn.jpg/

Just do be clear about my objectives for this package. JOB_NAME, CATEGORY_ID, RUN_DATE, RUN_TIME, RUN_DURATION and PLAN_NAME all go into the TBL_SQL_JOBS table. The PLAN_DETAILS column will do nothing for nulls (as will PLAN_NAME) but for populated records it will remove the "Databases: " string and split the comma delimited database names. Then it needs to check the DB names from the split against the TBL_Databases table (previously populated) and grab the corresponding ID. Then, combined with the ID of the current job record we are processing (think the "lookup job ID" part of the last task of the package) we add those records to the TBL_DATABASE_JOBS table separately. The end result being a table with a list of unique DBs and a table with a list of Historical Job info and a table between that provides a 1 job: to many DB relationship. Thanks again.

Comment: we're never gentle, but we try to be polite.  There's a 101010 button above your edit area that will help format your code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your script solution is the way to go.  And, you don't need to worry about inserting from the script.

You can limit the role of the script to only handle the splitting of the comma-separated list.  The output of the script would be one row for each item in the list.

The important step is to set the script component to be asynchronous.  Asynchronous mode with enable the component to output a different number of rows than the input number of rows.  After creating a new script component as a Transformation, edit the component.  Select the Input and Output Properties, select Output 0.  Change the value for the SynchronousInputID property to None.  Expand The Output 0 branch and Add Columns to the Output Columns branch.  The columns will comprise the rows that exit the component.  Finally, add your script code that will create a row for each item in your comma-separated list.

Once you can export one row for each item in the list, add a destination just like any other destination.